# Google Calendar API PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to search Google Calendar by created (item field).
This fails to give any results.

```
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    "q"=>"created>2020-06-14T16:09:16.000Z"
    );
$results = $this->service->events->listEvents("primary", $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
```

I have also tried to test this 'q' search with timeMin

```
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    "q"=>"timeMin>2020-06-14T16:09:16.000Z"
    );
$results = $this->service->events->listEvents("primary", $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
```

and the same issue with no results.

Events, calendar access and $this->service are proven with much the same code, but using timeMin as optional parameter instead of 'q'

```
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    "timeMin"=>"2020-06-14T16:09:16.000Z" // *** note this is instead of 'Q' ***
    );
$results = $this->service->events->listEvents("primary", $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
```

My question is what is actually permissable when searching using 'q' and how should it be constructed. As expected the Google documentation is very vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [event.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/lis) you will see that

> q string  Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in any field, except for extended properties. Optional.

Its a free text search string.  This means that you can search on the name of an even or a description.

The following would return any even that had a title or a description of birthday.

```
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    "q"=>"Birthday"
    );
$results = $this->service->events->listEvents("primary", $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
```

That it is a free text search on any field i tried to do a search on a date from one of my events and that sadly did not work.

```
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    "q"=>"2008-09-22T13:43:40.000Z"
    );
$results = $this->service->events->listEvents("primary", $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
```

What you should be doing is something more along the lines of

```
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    "mintime"=>"2012-03-19T08:42:11.000Z",
    "maxtime"=>"2012-03-19T10:42:11.000Z"
    );
$results = $this->service->events->listEvents("primary", $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
```

which will return the events based upon your time.  Unfortunately this is not the created time it searches on but rather the event time.

Comment: Thanks for explaining 'q' and testing its free text search. So 'q' basically might search a value across all AND any any of the fields for a value. This is such a vague data search particularly when we don't know exactly what is searched and what is not. Absolutely useless if you ask me, but thanks for demonstrating. I am angry just imagining the MySQL equivalent - "select item from events where (maybecolumn1=value1 or maybecolumn2=value1 or maybecolumn3=value1) or (maybecolumn1=value2 or maybecolumn2=value2 or maybecolumn3=value2)"